# how to launch shell buffers automatically when launching emacs/spacemacs

Tags: shell, emacs, spacemacs

I am using spacemacs. I am developing a web c++ app, usually, I will open a few shell buffers for building, launch c++ web server, redeploy css/js code. So I named them: shell-build, shell-launch, shell-deploy.
I want to know if there is a way to launch them automatically every time when I launch spacemacs.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if they need to open in the background or not, but if not, putting this in the user-config section of your .spacemacs should do the trick:

```
(mapc #'shell '("shell-build"
                "shell-launch"
                "shell-deploy"))
```

`mapc` passes the items in the list to the shell command, one by one, discarding the return result of the function.